# Redux hook useSelector not giving proper state

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to get Redux state out of the global store and when I use `useSelector` in a `WithAuth` HOC I am not getting the proper state. On my global state there are two keys: `currentUser` and `currentUser.isAuthenticated`.

In my Redux dev tools, the `isAuthenticated` key shows having the value `true`, but when I make use of the hook, I get `false`.

I've had a look at the [official documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector), but I couldn't find anything which might help me, if I've read it correctly.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I am new to using hooks for Redux. Thanks.

**withAuth.tsx**

```
import   React,
       { useEffect }          from "react";
import { useSelector }        from "react-redux";
import { useHistory }         from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes }             from "../../constants/RoutesNames";
import { DefaultRootState }   from "../../store/reducers";

interface Props
{
    ComponentToBeRendered: React.FC<unknown>
    props?: any
};

const stateSelector = (state: DefaultRootState) => state.currentUser.isAuthenticated;

const WithAuth : React.FC<Props> = ({ ComponentToBeRendered, props }) =>
{

    const isAuthenticated = useSelector<DefaultRootState, boolean>(stateSelector);
    const history         = useHistory();

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        if (!isAuthenticated)  history.push(Routes.SIGN_IN);

    }, [ isAuthenticated, history ]);

    return (
        <ComponentToBeRendered {...props} />
    )
}

export default WithAuth;
```

Comment: Probably `isAuthenticated` is set after your HOC runs, you may need an `isAuthenticating` value as well.

Comment: @HMR Hi, thanks for replying. I would strongly consider doing that but I'm not sure exactly how I would determine a loading state for `useSelector`. It does produce a value immediately, just the wrong one. And if a user is not logged in, even on update the hook will produce the value `false` again (I think).

Comment: @HMR I think one possibility is to initialize a counter to `0` outside the HOC and increment it in the HOC and reroute or not only if the counter is at least `1`. But that seems kind of hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `useSelector` hook does a double take on the Redux state. If you `console.log` (`console.log("Got isAuth", isAuthenticated);`) inside the `useEffect` hook you will see that the first log will be `Got isAuth false` and the second `Got isAuth true`.

I don't know if that's the whole story, but for now I've re-implemented `WithAuth` to accept a rendered element rather than a component to be rendered. And then I conditionally return that element or my sign in page rendered. Thus,

```
import   React                from "react";
import { useSelector }        from "react-redux";
import   AuthFlow             from "../../pages/AuthFlow";
import { DefaultRootState }   from "../../store/reducers";

interface Props
{
    ComponentToBeRendered: React.ReactElement;
};

const isAuthenticatedSelector = (state: DefaultRootState) => state.currentUser.isAuthenticated;

const WithAuth : React.FC<Props> = React.memo(({ ComponentToBeRendered }) =>
{

    const isAuthenticated = useSelector<DefaultRootState, boolean>(isAuthenticatedSelector);

    return (
      isAuthenticated ? ComponentToBeRendered : <AuthFlow />
    )
})

export default WithAuth;
```

I don't know if this is the best approach, but I've found a workaround for now. Strange that `useSelector` can't just get the Redux state correctly on the first run. Maybe I'm missing something someone can show me.

=========== **EDIT** ===========

I thought a little more about this and I think this approach might be slightly better for various reasons

```
import   React                from "react";
import { useSelector }        from "react-redux";
import   BasicTextLink        from "../../components/BasicLink/BasicLink";
import { Routes }             from "../../constants/RoutesNames";
import { DefaultRootState }   from "../../store/reducers";

interface Props
{
    ElementToBeShown: React.ReactElement;
};

const isAuthenticatedSelector = (state: DefaultRootState) => state.currentUser.isAuthenticated;

const WithAuth : React.FC<Props> = React.memo(({ ElementToBeShown }) =>
{

    const isAuthenticated = useSelector<DefaultRootState, boolean>(isAuthenticatedSelector);

    return (
      isAuthenticated ? ElementToBeShown : <h2>You are not signed in. Please {
        <BasicTextLink baseColor useHoverEffect darkHover to={Routes.SIGN_IN} underline={"hover"}>
          sign in
        </BasicTextLink>
        } first</h2>
    )
});

export default WithAuth;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the wrong value? Could you add more info to the problem?

Also remember you can shorthand the return of a statement like this to keep code cleaner:

```
   const stateSelector = (state: DefaultRootState) => state.currentUser.isAuthenticated
```

Comment: Hi Ausgtin, thanks for replying. Yes, that's correct, thank you for pointing that out, I've made the changes on my post.

Comment: Where do you check the value of `isAuthenticated` that returns false? `useSelector` will always return the current value of that key in Redux state as the documentation says. It must be another thing

Comment: Since `WithAuth` is an HOC, I'm using `isAuthenticated` only there in the `useEffect` hook. It's a really strange issue because I'm also using the `useDispatch` hook elsewhere and that works just fine and my state gets set properly.

Comment: I think it is related to when the code is executed or that you are missing something in the middle of checking the redux state value in DevTools vs. checking in the code. But cant help much there

Comment: Hi Agustin, please see my answer. Maybe that will shed more light on the situation.  Thanks.